# Is it okay to use the method's name for a variable in a method?

Tags: java

Is this considered a bad practice?
Specifically, is it okay if i use the name "average" as both a local variable within the method "average"?

```
public static double average(double[] arr) {
    double average = 0.0;
    for (int = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        average += arr[i];
    }
    average /= arr.length;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: average is good for a variable name, but it is a lousy method name. either way, when looking at syntax, there's nothing wrong with it

Comment: Does it compile? Pass tests? If so, it's opinion based.

Comment: `Methods should be verbs`

Comment: Depends. How do you define "okay"?

Comment: It's a good practice to name methods as verbs. In your example, it can be `countAverage`

Comment: @ScaryWombat `average` is a verb. I can _average_ 1, 2, and 3 to get 2.

Comment: @Stultuske. It's fine as both. It can be a verb too.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes it does compile

Comment: @NicHartley Good point

Comment: @dehasi. English is a mighty language indeed

Comment: You guys raised a very good point that the method name should be a verb, that will resolve this problem actually! :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist there's more to a method name than "just being a verb". It should also tell what the method is doing, and imo, it doesn't do that.

Comment: While I certainly appreciate the value of naming things such that it facilitates understanding for/to others, voted to close because it still remains a fact that there is no hard science that can decide such matters and therefore indeed it is just opinions.

Comment: (In FORTRAN, when you defined a function, that automatically created a "local variable" that you assigned to in order to control the value returned at function exit.  So in that setting it was even an imposed rule that some variable's name was equal to the function's.)

Comment: As it causes confusion, it's a bad practice: if you see the word `average`, does it mean the function name or the variable? I use prefixes for variables (like 'g_' for global (static) variables) and 'str_', 'int_', … for local variables (where `str_` means `string`, `int_` means `integer`, …). Class definition gets CAPS, like `AverageCalculator` and the methods are verbs, starting with a small letter, like `countAverage()`. This is just a way of working, but it makes everything clear. There are different ways for doing this, but following a code guideline is always a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That variable isn't representing the `average`, it's representing the `sum`. You should name it that.

```
public static double average(double[] arr) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum / arr.length;
}
```

Comment: So it's better to change it to rename it to sum, do the for loop, then return sum / length?

Comment: @ShawnKoh IMO, yes; variable names are pointless if you don't use them to show what the variable contains

Comment: And now the OP discovers that he is running into overflows, and decides to use the running-average algorithm instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally **method** name should express a function of what it is doing.

for example , `calculateAverage`.

More from Java doc.

**Naming a Method**

*Although a method name can be any legal identifier, code conventions restrict method names. By convention, method names should be a verb in lowercase or a multi-word name that begins with a verb in lowercase, followed by adjectives, nouns, etc. In multi-word names, the first letter of each of the second and following words should be capitalized*. Here are some examples:

run
runFast
getBackground
getFinalData
compareTo
setX
isEmpty

Typically, a method has a unique name within its class. However, a method might have the same name as other methods due to method overloading.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: There are exceptions, non of the methods in the Math helper class are verbs and can you imagine typing caluateABS(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: I agree with him, I think that `calculateAverage` is better, as It is more clear, as then we know that we are not getting the value but we are doing some process to calculate It.

Comment: @RichardStokes the guideline is for writing method in custom classes keeping the view of good coding practices

Comment: you do not have an attribute ABS is not the same

Comment: @vmrvictor yes.

Comment: and that it is in java class libraries do not mean it is done in the perfect way, is just another way of doing things

Comment: I would disagree, guidelines are guidelines they are not blanket rules. Yes they should be taken within consideration but there will be exceptions, ultimately you also have to use some common sense. In this case yes I think it's fine to have a method variable that is the same name method name and also that the method name is not a verb

Comment: as for "calculateAverage is better" : now it requires 9 more keystrokes before the user arrives at the first token that will help the IDE's autocomplete.  Ergonomics matter too.

Comment: @ErwinSmout right but here the question was regarding method name, so truly its opinion based.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about the Math methods and having those all named calculateXYZ.  Should delete that comment but can't any longer.